# Ajax jquery toggle button

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the code, I'm using toggle. I want to toggle when the index.php has loaded. In the code below, when I click it opens up and close by itself. I placed the toggle before, and when Click it works BUT for the first time I have to click the button twice.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#btn").click(function(){ 

            // $("#output").toggle("slow",function(){ // placed before

            $("#output").load("index.php",null,function(){ 

        $("#output").toggle("slow"); // placed after

        })
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Note: Index.php files generates a list of links. when I click on the button need it show and hide the list.

I also did load the content first and toggle second, as mentionned In the reply below. But when I click on the button it opens and hides on first click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's cause your `#output` in **not hidden**, it just has no content, so it's **visible**.
Than what you do, you populate it with content and than... *violá* `toggle()` hides it.

Make it hidden first:

```
$(function(){

    var $output = $('#output'); // cache your selectors

    $output.hide(); // !!

    $("#btn").click(function(){ 
        $output.load("index.php",null,function(){ 
          $output.toggle(800); // placed inside
        });
    }); 

});
```

but still above there's no need to call `.load()` on every button click so to fix that:

```
    $output.hide(); // !!

    function toggleOutput(){
        $output.toggle(800);
    }

    $("#btn").click(function(){
        if($output.is(':visible')) return toggleOutput(); // If visible
        $output.load("index.php", null, toggleOutput);    // else
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#btn").click(function(){ 

            // if #output is going to be shown then load
            $("#output").load("index.php");

            $("#output").toggle("slow");
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("#btn").click(function(){ 

        // $("#output").toggle("slow",function(){ // placed before

        $("#output").load("index.php",null,function(){      
    }).toggle("slow"); // Chained
    }); 
});
```